# Can't run ibm_db in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: db2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run ibm_db in a jupyter notebook. When I run ibm_db I get the below error.

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import ibm_db

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myName/anaconda/envs/householding/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libdb2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myName/anaconda/envs/householding/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

When i run os.getcwd() I get '/Users/myName'

What I think is happening is that because my current directory is to levels down from the start of the path dlopen is looking for, it is failing. I've done some looking around but can't find a way to change where dlopen is looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually update your environment variable

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
to include
/ibm_db-2.0.8-py3.6-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/clidriver/lib

If you have installed ibm_db-2.0.8 on python3.6,
On terminal write

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/myName/anaconda/envs/householding/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.8-py3.6-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/clidriver/lib
```

It should work like a charm after this.
For reference checkout this:[Issues with MAC OS X](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/tree/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db#issues-with-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and found that the installDSDriver script creates a file at /Applications/dsdriver/db2profile stating the below:

```sh
# NAME:     db2profile
#
# FUNCTION: This script sets up a default database environment for
#           Bourne shell or Korn shell users.
#
#           This file is tuned for IBM Data Server Driver Package only.
#
# USAGE:    . db2profile
#           This script can either be invoked directly as above or
#           it can be added to the user's .profile file so that the
#           database environment is established during login.
#
```

so I just added on my ~/.bash_profile the line below:

`source /Applications/dsdriver/db2profile`

Open a new terminal window or restart and should work.
This file exports all the environment variables needed for the db2cli command to work.